# How to link resources in a Django page

Tags: python, django

Let's suppose I have an HTML page (base.html) that must include one JavaScript file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.js"></script>
```

It is my understanding that a Django project is not hosted in a public folder. Rather, requests are routed to `views.py` which generates a response.

Let's suppose my project directory looks like this

```
- project
- project_app
    - views, models, ecc…
- templates
    - base.html
    - css
        - main.css
    - js
        - main.js
```

How come `base.html` can reference `main.css` and `main.js`? If I access `myserver.com/js/main.js` this should not return anything (as the template folder is not public). Yet the browser need to access those file and I need to include them.

Do I need to write a specific URL rule to redirect requests to `/js/main.js` to the actual js file or what sort of magic can make a simple html include works?

Comment: What does your urls.py look like?

Comment: i just left the default one, plus a redirect to a view using base.html

Comment: Well, that shouldn't actually work. If you are able to access `/js/main.js` it is most likely django's `runserver` magic serving `STATIC_ROOT` at `STATIC_URL`. It certainly won't work in production. You should be serving `STATIC_ROOT` at `STATIC_URL` via a webserver of your choice, then using django's `static` tag to generate all asset URLS.

Comment: Indeed, I never told it is working nor that it should.

Comment: @Saturnix, you implied so by saying "How come `base.html` can reference `main.css`...", as if it could.

Comment: Yep... This was more of an hypothetical question, since I could see the error coming before even trying to do something (and, indeed, the error would have arised, as your comment is stating) - I realized I sound like an asshole in my response to your comment only when I couldn't edit it anymore :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual method is to keep your CSS, javascript, and similar files in a `static` folder and serve them to your html. General Django documentation can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/).

In a nutshell, your directory will look like this:

```
- project
- project_app
    - views, models, ecc…
- templates
    - base.html
- static
    - css
        - main.css
    - js
        - main.js
```

Then, your `base.html` will reference the file using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.js"></script>
```

The docs I referenced at the top show how to serve static files in production. Lots of people use a content delivery network (CDN) to serve their static files. Amazon's S3 service is an example of this. Then, you'll change the `STATIC_URL` setting in your `settings.py` to your S3 bucket (or similar network). You can then reference the `STATIC_URL` in your templates.

```
{% load static %}
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>
...
```

You'll use commands like `./manage.py collectstatic` to collect your static files and move them to your CDN at certain times. Basics of `collectstatic` can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic).

Answer (score 1):

You need to put all your static files in STATIC_ROOT folder by using command django-admin.py collectstatic and serve this folder. More details and explanation you can find here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#managing-static-files-css-images